# Javascript Sorting - Strange behaviour, any idea?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

If I do

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'k'].sort( function(a,b){ return a.length - b.length } )
```

it outputs

> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "k"]

But when I do (added one element 'l' at the end)

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'k', 'l'].sort( function(a,b){ return a.length - b.length } )
```

it outputs

> ["f", "a", "c", "d", "e", "b", "g", "h", "i", "k", "l"]

Is there any specific reason why this is happening or is this just a quirk?

PS: related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37006813/nth-longest-string-sortation). I tested it on chrome and it has been bugging me since yesterday :)

Comment: @Alnitak Sorry for that, I have explained the difference between arrays

Comment: My guess? It moves the middle element to the front when doing the quicksort pass, then bails out / sorts the rest with insert sort.

Comment: bizarrely I don't see this behaviour if I sort `1..9` with a `return 0` comparator

Comment: In any case, the order of equal elements after sorting is undefined.

Comment: @Alnitak try 0..11. IIRC, at least one library sort implementation uses and the de-facto standard is insertion up to 10-element sub-arrays and quick-sort above.

Comment: @JanDvorak ah, yes, there it goes...

Comment: @JanDvorak thanks, can you point out the source of this info in spec here http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.sort ?

Comment: @gurvinder372 it's almost certainly not in the spec - the spec doesn't mandate a "stable sort" so the fact that the two different implementations (one of which is stable, for up to 10 elements, and the other that isn't) is still conformant.

Comment: @gurv which part? That it doesn't require a stable sort? That chrome shall choose quicksort  + insertion?

Comment: @JanDvorak last part (change of sorting algo based on number of elements). I am just trying to see which all other array will it affect.

Comment: @Alnitak thanks, can you please share a full answer explaining why this unexpected behaviour is still in conformance ?

Comment: The browser may choose any sorting algorithm it wishes. That's as far as the spec is concerned. For all the spec knows. The browser is fully entitled to shuffle the array randomly before passing it to qiucksort. That browsers choose to avoid worst case scenario in a better way is just a nice bonus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't found chapter and verse in the current V8 code, but [this bug ticket](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=90) says that Chrome uses insertion sort for arrays of length <= 10, and quicksort otherwise.

The insertion sort algorithm is stable, that is to say that given two equal elements it'll preserve their relative positions in the array.  The quick sort algorithm on the other hand is unstable - it will leave equal elements in random relative positions.

This is all allowable [per the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.sort):

> The sort is not necessarily stable (that is, elements that compare equal do not necessarily remain in their original order)

Users *must not* rely upon the sort order being deterministic.

Answer (score 1):

You sort by a criteria (the length) that is the same for all your values (i.e. 1). Therefore any order is a correctly sorted one. The native sort implementation does not guarantee to keep the order, if the input is already sorted.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour will most likely be caused by the implementation (e.g. quicksort). However please keep in mind that javascript is behaving correctly here.

The contract of your comparison function says that if 0 is returned, both values are equal and their order does not matter. 
It does not say that they should remain in the same order.

My theory why you get these resukts is that quicksort recursively splits your arrays in half at the middle. This will most likely have differnt results for arrays with an even length that for arrays with an odd lenght.

Comment: you should test that theory - my tests indicate that it's incorrect

Comment: that's why I said it's a theory. To find out, you would probably need to look into the source code of the JS Engine implementation. But then again, according to spec, this behaviour is fine

Comment: it's a theory that's so trivially tested that I had already done so (and ruled it out) before you posted your answer...

Answer (score -1):

It happens because of [Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) implemented in JavaScript VM. Your custom function return 0 in any case because all your strings length is 1 so it's basically just like:

`['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'k'].sort( function(a,b){ return 0 } )`